# Python catch exception "pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am facing problem with my malfunction csv input file whole reading and which i can deal with by adding **"error_bad_lines=False"** in my read_csv func to remove those.

But i need to report these many files which is creating the problem, I assumed that i need to catch that exception. And i tried it via using

```
except pd.parser.CParserError
```

and

```
except ExceptionSubclass as exceptionsubclass:
```

After searching over Internet, in both the cases i am not able to catch this exception, if you have any idea how to report all the malfunction file please let me know.

Error i am getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 134, in reading_csv
    df = pd.read_csv(absolute_path_of_file, sep=',', dtype=str, keep_default_na=False)
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 890, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:10862)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 912, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:11138)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 966, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:11884)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 953, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:11755)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2184, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:28765)
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 22, saw 8
```

Answer (score 7):

Try using `except pd.errors.ParserError` instead of `except pd.parser.CParserError`.

This is the [exception](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.errors.ParserError.html) that is raised by pandas.

Comment: i used all the mentioned exception class "except pandas.errors.ParserError:" | "except pandas.errors.DtypeWarning:" | "except pandas.errors.EmptyDataError:" and others but unable to catch our scenario.

Comment: #Nordle any idea how to do that

Comment: And `except Exception` isn't catching it?

Comment: @Nordle except Exception works, thanks! Was looking for the same solution to the same problem. :)
Is there still no way to pinpoint a pandas ParserError non-generally without "except Exception" yet?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.errors.ParserError.html)

```
from pandas.errors import ParserError
try:
    ...
except ParserError:
    ...
```

or  simple

```
except pd.errors.ParserError  as text_exception:
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
from dateutil.parser import ParserError
```